# Rewrite url to a file with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite an URL looks like

> https://test.com/foo/bar/test.docx

to a file in my logs. `e.g. /var/log/foo/bar/test.docx`

Is it possible with `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: Could you please show the code that you've tried?

Comment: Sure that is possible, you just have to do it. And in addition you need to grant access to that file system section to your http server, the path looks like it is _not_ part of the section the http server is granted access to. And... by the way... a MS word file certainly is nothing that belongs into a `log` directory...